# How to set different colors for one Tkinter Label?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm using `Tkinter` to make a GUI program,and here is a problem:For exmaple,there is a `Label` object,I want to set text for it and make the text color different.For example,I want to set "I like to eat apple",and I want "I" is red color,"like to" is yellow color and "eat apple" is green color.

I don't want to use multi Labels because it will make my program more complex and the number of colors is dynamic so i can't decide it at first.

Anyone can tell me how to make it? Thanks very much!

Comment: You can't use multiple colors in a label.

Comment: As Brian said, you can't use multiple colors in a label. Your best alternative is either generating many labels (which you *can* do dynamically), or switching to a different format (HTML+CSS is good at presentation).

Comment: widget [Text](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) can display text with different colors.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a similar question that had the same answer: use a Text widget and and make it read-only, so it is effectively a label.